# Declare function Javascript to C# - Unity

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code in Javascript

VoxelizationTest.js

```
public var drawMeshShell = true;
public var drawMeshInside = true;
public var drawEmptyCube = true;
public var meshShellPositionFromObject = Vector3.zero;
private var aABCGrids : Array;

function Voxelize (gameObject : GameObject, cubeSide : float) {
var thisObjGrid : Voxelization.AABCGrid;
var objectVoxels = 0;
var emptySpaceVoxels = 0;

aABCGrids = new Array();    
thisObjGrid = Voxelization.CreateGridWithGameObjectMesh(gameObject, 
cubeSide, true, drawMeshInside);
aABCGrids.Push(thisObjGrid);
for(var aABCGrid : Voxelization.AABCGrid in aABCGrids) {
    if(drawMeshShell && aABCGrid) {
        var cubeSize = new Vector3(cubeSide, cubeSide, cubeSide);
        var gridSize = aABCGrid.GetSize();
        for(var x = 0; x < gridSize.x; ++x) {
            for(var y = 0; y < gridSize.y; ++y) {
                for(var z = 0; z < gridSize.z; ++z) {
                    var cubeCenter = 
                     aABCGrid.GetAABCCenterFromGridCenter(x,y, z) + 
                            aABCGrid.GetCenter() + 
                                meshShellPositionFromObject;
                    if(aABCGrid.IsAABCSet(x, y, z)) {
                        objectVoxels++;
                    } else if (drawEmptyCube) {
                        emptySpaceVoxels++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
Debug.Log("Objeto: "+gameObject+" voxeles: "+objectVoxels);
return [objectVoxels, emptySpaceVoxels];
}
```

I need implement the function and use its value that return in C# but this not works, Is there something like that?
The code is for Unity , the IDE is visual studio
this is the code , i instance as a class but not works

```
VoxelizationTest script= new VoxelizationTest();
```

Test.cs

```
float volume_cm3 = 0, emptySpace_cm3 = 0;
int[] voxels = new int[2];

VoxelizationTest script= new VoxelizationTest();
voxels = script.Voxelize (GameObject.Find (pair.Value.name), 0.015f);
volume_cm3 = voxels[0] * Mathf.Pow(1.5f, 3);
emptySpace_cm3 = voxels[1] * Mathf.Pow(1.5f, 3);
Debug.Log ("Voxels object: " + voxels[0] + " VolumeCm3: 
                    " + volume_cm3 + " emptySpaceCm3: " + emptySpace_cm3);
float shapeRelation =  emptySpace_cm3 / (emptySpace_cm3 
                    + volume_cm3);
if(shapeRelation > mayor)
mayor = shapeRelation;
objectsShapeRelation.Add (pair.Value, shapeRelation);
```

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/205738/cross-referencing-between-unityscript-and-c.html

Comment: Rather than trying to cross reference to C# from Javascript, just convert to using C# all the time. You can switch over with (IIRC) about 3 simple regex replacements. Or [use this tool](http://www.m2h.nl/files/js_to_c.php).

Comment: I need the file of javascript